# How do you decode/decrypt a SignedCMS/PKCS#7 in C# PCL

Tags: c#, xamarin, asp.net-web-api2, portable-class-library, pkcs#7

So, I have an WebAPI that is returning a PKCS#7 file to a client. The client is written as a C# PCL so it can be used in Xamarin iOS and Android projects.

My initial tests worked fine because I was encoding and decoding in my unit tests and could use the Pkcs library. It seems I can't find any way of decoding the data on the client because I don't know of any Pkcs library that works with a PCL.

Can someone tell me how/if this can be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I did end up switching my project to .netstandard 1.4 and using Portable.BouncyCastle to decode the Cms created on the server side.

Here is the code that I used to decode the Cms. I'm sort of trusting that this is also checking the signature since there is no explicit method for doing that in BouncyCastle like there is via the framework code i.e. CheckSignature().

```
var cmsParser = new Org.BouncyCastle.Cms.CmsSignedDataParser(dataBytes);
var cmsSignedContent = cmsParser.GetSignedContent();
var contentStream = cmsSignedContent.ContentStream;
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
contentStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
byte[] contentBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
var decodedContent = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(contentBytes);
```

In addition I added this to verify the signer info:

```
cmsParser.GetSignedContent().Drain();
var certStore = cmsParser.GetCertificates("Collection");
var signerInfos = cmsParser.GetSignerInfos();
var signers = signerInfos.GetSigners();

foreach (SignerInformation signer in signers)
{
    var certCollection = certStore.GetMatches(signer.SignerID);
    foreach (Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate cert in certCollection)
    {
        var result = signer.Verify(cert);
        if (!result)
        {
            throw new Exception("Certificate verification error, the signer could not be verified.");
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not 100% sure if this is all I need to do but my client's will communicate via SSL and they are using an HMAC auth with an appId and client secret so I'm not so concerned with in transit issues. I'm basically transferring a "license" file and I want to make sure the contents are not tampered with after it has been saved on the client device.

If anyone has any suggestions or concerns with this please let me know.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I currently use [PCLCrypto](https://github.com/AArnott/PCLCrypto) to encrypt and decrypt using PKCS#7 on the client (in a Xamarin Forms project). I assume it will do what you need as well.

The PKCS#7 wiki example can be found [here](https://github.com/AArnott/PCLCrypto/wiki/Crypto-Recipes#perform-aes-encryptiondecryption)

Comment: Ok, so I thought that with PKCS7 the included cert was used to decrypt the contents. In the PCLCrypto example code they are supplying "keyMaterial" as byte[]. How do I get the cert out of the PKCS container to use? On the server side you use SignedCms and then just .Decode() it and it uses the cert behind the scenes (or at least I thought that's what it did)

Comment: @jmichas So I was actually just encrypting and decrypting strings on the client not certificates. Wonder if you can export or somehow extract the data from the certificate. What kind of certificate object are you trying to work with? There is also [BouncyCastle-PCL](https://github.com/onovotny/BouncyCastle-PCL) which looks like it might have some certificate and CMS related code but it is not something I have ever looked into and looks to be lacking on documentation unless it is saved somewhere else.

Comment: I'm using a pfx on the server side and signing the cms with it as an X509Certificate2. I think that part is working correctly. The problem is I don't know of any library for the client side. I also made a .netstandard 1.4 version of my client library and tried to use the built in system.security stuff but unfortunately the .netstandard stuff doesn't include SignedCms. It does have EnvelopedCms but I think that requires me to share the key/cert. I was trying to make it so consumers didn't need to worry about installing a cert.

Comment: @jmichas Unfortunately I do not know enough about it. If you are only targeting Android and iOS, you could move up to .Net Standard 1.6. Not sure if that has what you need or not. You could also always package the certificate with your app if that is the problem.

Comment: Yeah, I switched to .netstandard 1.4 because it looked like Portable.BouncyCastle has what I needed and it was only available for standard. Thanks!